# Winforms PropertyGrid per-GridItem row height

Tags: winforms, propertygrid

I'm using the Winforms `PropertyGrid`; the target of the `SelectedObject` includes a property of type `Image`. Everything is fine, except that with all items the same height, the image is too small to see properly. I'd like to have some control over the height of grid items such that the image can be displayed a bit larger. One other detail is that the `SelectedObject` of one `PropertyGrid` control may be assigned an object of any of a variety of different classes (which may or may not have image properties), so I'm hoping the height can be driven by data in the instance of the `SelectedObject` itself, rather than making it a static behavior of the control, although I'd settle for a custom attribute of the image property to make the item height at least class-specific if it can't be instance-specific.

How can I do this? Custom attribute? `PropertyGrid` event? Something else?

Comment: Grid row height is fixed and is the same for all properties (It's the Font height + 2). You can't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Simon commented on your question, this is not possible to have a custom height for a GridItem.

You have 2 solutions to be able to show an image with a reasonable size:

1. You can code your own [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx). That way, the user would just click the down arrow and see a nicely sized image in the dropdown box.
2. Sorry for the plug but I think it directly answers your question: only 3rd party PropertyGrids may allow you to get variable size rows in the grid. [Smart PropertyGrid.Net](http://visualhint.com) is one of them. You set a HeightMultiplier to the row so that it expands on let's say 4 rows. Then you code your own Look class that handles the drawing of the image the way you want in this space.

Comment: Although I'm using the winforms property grid, it's actually in a WPF app. I had looked into property grid for WPF a while ago, but wasn't happy with what I was finding. Issues included componentmodel support, intrinsic support for data types such as dates, etc. In all, I found that the basic winforms property grid as shipped with .NET seemed the path of least programming effort to achieve an acceptable look and feel and level of functionality (the app started as winforms, evolved to WPF). If I'm going to commit to a swap out, I think I'd prefer to see what's currently available for WPF.